# Twitter share box url parameter won't show up

Tags: twitter, query-string, tweets

I'm trying to dynamically generate my own custom tweet button using this line of php.

```
echo "<li><a href=\"javascript:\" onclick=\"javascript:
popitup('https://twitter.com/share?text=Check%20out%20{$items[$i]
['name']}%20at%20&url=cmplt.st/item/{$items[$i]
['item_id']}&via=cmpltst&counturl=completeset.us/items/{$items[$i]['item_id']}')\"
class=\"twitter\">T</a></li>";
```

The problem is that the URL parameter isn't showing up in the share box. I'm trying to get the share box to display `Check out {item name} at cmplt.st/item/{item'item_id}` where `cmplt.st/item/{item'item_id}` links to `completeset.us/items/{item_id}`, but it only displays `Check out {item name} at`. How can I get the url to actually show up in the tweet?

EDIT:

Here's the popitup function. All it does it pop up the share box in a separate window.

```
//Function to pop up a new window
function popitup(url) {
   newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=300,width=500');
   if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
   return false;
}
```

Comment: `&` in a URL is used to separate query-string parameters. To pass the entire URL along, try using its escape sequence (`%26`) instead. `...at%20%26url=...`

Comment: That gives me `Check out Big Kid Blank at &url=cmplt.st/item/sjDDulC8wt http://completeset.us/organizer via @cmpltst` because it freaks out about there not being a url parameter.

Comment: Can you post code for your `popitup` function?

Comment: Looking at your question again, are you sure you aren't confusing your `url` parameter with showing a URL in the text description?

Comment: Shouldn't the URL parameter show up in the tweet box? The URL for the page does if I leave it blank. Besides, if I simply put the URL in the text parameter I can't shorten it because it doesn't apply the countURL to it.

Comment: Adding http:// to both the url and counturl parameters solved the problem of my custom url not appearing, though the browser still tries to literally navigate to the url parameter rather than the one I specified for counturl.

Comment: That was my mistake, I thought that url was the address it showed and counturl was the one it actually navigated to. The countrul is just the address it uses for counting the number of users who have tweeted a page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the URL not showing up was simply that I didn't have an http:// on the front. For some reason Twitter despises naked domains. I believe that the code they use to parse URLs doesn't recognize addresses that don't have http(s):// on the front. I've found that whenever I'm having a problem with twitter, checking the URLs is a good place to start.